# Handle non JSON Response with Generic Codable API client

Tags: ios, swift

I have an API client that uses generic API response that conforms to Codable Protocol and uses `JSONDecoder` to decode the response as shown below, how do I handle having a response which doesn't return JSON ( status code 201 created)?

```
dataRequest.validate().responseJSON { response in

     if let error = response.error {
        completion(.failure(error.localizedDescription))
     } else if let data = response.data {
        do {
           let apiResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.Response.self, from: data)
           completion(.success(apiResponse))
        } catch {
           completion(.failure(error.localizedDescription))
        }
     } else {
        completion(.failure("Something went wrong, please try again later."))
     }
  }
```

It returns this error:
the response could not be serialized input data was nil or zero-length

Comment: Unrelated but **never ever** return or print `localizedDescription` of a `DecodingError`. Catch `DecodingError` explicitly and handle `context` and `debugDescription` to get a comprehensive error description.

Comment: You can check status code like this: response.response?.statusCode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you can look at the `statusCode` property of the `response` (assuming that it is a `HTTPURLResponse`) and make your determination about whether or not there will be a body to parse. I would put it immediately after the error check.